# Display html content in an ASP.NET Textbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Its often that we need to display some formatted html text in a Web page. Here is what I want to do
There is a description field where user enters his comments.There's anther History field which shows some history about the user edits done. I just want to bold the User comments. Everything else in History Text box can be normal text.
Now I have two options here

1. Let the User bold his comments by using a third party editor like TINYMCE or CKEDITOR.
2. Let me bold the text after the user clicks submit button on the Page and render it in History control.

If we use Approach 1, It will be an Issue to show html content in History control which is a plain Text box.
Similarly in approach 2, we can't directly display formatted text in history control and storing htmltags in DB might be an issue.

Now, I am in a confusion which approach is right and how to achieve this.Kindly comment with your expert views and suggestions
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered keeping meta data as well as the original plain text. The meta data might say which words are user comments and then you could render them later however you wanted.

Comment: Why do you want to put History in a text box, you want your history to be editable?

Comment: What do u mean by metadata? Its just a text in a user comments textbox contol .though we know the metadata how do we render to user

Comment: No history is read only textbox

Comment: Instead of creating a read-only textbox, create a custom HTML design and using CSS show user a disabled textbox like UI. Using CSS you can customize your content as you want, and you can make your history comments bold etc using CSS as well.

Comment: Any working example for this idea would be helpful